# Visibility="Gone" not working for me

Tags: android, textview, visibility

I have this block of code sitting in my XMl. 
For Some reason, the view is still visible.
I have other blocks that make it visible at specific points in time, but I already commented them out. This is the last block of code with this view standing and for some reason I can still see it.

To my best knowledge this did work at some point, I do recall that it was "gone" and then "visible" when I needed it to be.

Can anyone give me an idea as to why this is happening?

I did refactor my package, and I don't recall if it was it was visible before or not. But can that have anything do with the issue?

Thanks!

```
<TextView
            android:id="@+id/kelErechApaim"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="testing now here! ahoajdkf"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:visibility="gone" />
```

Here is the commented JavaCode:

```
//     activity.findViewById(R.id.kelErechApaim).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

It says that R is an unused import.
Would that have anything to do with this?

```
import com.edon.freiner.siddur.R;
```

Comment: please provide the code

Comment: Are you changing the right file? This is a frequent mistake if you support multiple screens.

Comment: add java file code where you are making it visible

Comment: @Rohit52 yes, that is why I changed the text from the real text to "testing now here...." That shows up on the screen.

Comment: @zaidMirza I uploaded the code that is commented

Comment: @VishvaDave I uploaded the commented code

Comment: And yes, it is the correct activity

Comment: @EdonFreiner Make it visible in some if condition and in else make it gone. and by default gone

Comment: I can not guess the problem with one line of code.....

Comment: my code is thousands of lines long. I am not sure what parts you would need. this is an entire project spanning over dozens of classes. I have used android for about a year now. This is just mind boggling me. This view is not touched in the java code. Just here in the XML, why is it still showing up? I searched the entire java code this is the only occurrence of it. So why is it showing up. I am sorry that I cannot share the entire source code. I just don't know exactly what you need.

Comment: @zaidmirza ^^^^

Comment: @VishvaDave I could try that and let you know if it works, but I am doing this hundreds of times. I would rather make it cleaner and make it gone in the XML, and then Visible in the Java code

Comment: @VishvaDave, i tried making gone at the last point in my Java code, and it doesnt work

Comment: @EdonFreiner Sorry but i am not getting the error. may be you need some debugging. :(

Comment: @VishvaDave please tell me if you have any other ideas, I can send you all the code you want

Comment: I have seen this in code that works perfectly fine, upon upgrading the minsdk and target sdk ... Visbility.gone is not behaving consistently in the newer versions that worked fine in previous version...   I really wish Google would get their act together...    

I see this especially on the emulator... 

If anyone finds a solution let me know, because I see this as well and my code to use visiblity.gone worked fine until I changed the compile for most recent tarkets...

Comment: did you find the solution to this?

Answer (score -2):

There is two way to set visiblity

1.By XML

write android:visibility="gone" in that you don't want to visible

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/kelErechApaim"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="testing now here! ahoajdkf"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:visibility="gone" />
```

2.By Java Code

First you find the id of that item

```
 TextView tx;
    tx= (TextView )rootView.findViewById(R.id.yourid);//for fragment
    tx= (TextView )findViewById(R.id.yourid);//for Activity
     tx.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Comment: Correct, I want it Gone,

Comment: If you prepare multiple layout for diffrent screen then you have to change in all xml file having same name.This is a frequent mistake if you support multiple screens.